# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, cors, httprequest, access-control

I am using Flask to run two server on my localhost. One on port 40000 and the other on 50000. I have an HTML5 application running on localhost:50000. Now I want to send GET xml-http-requests to the server with port 40000.

I know this is not working because of the Same Origin Policy. Do I have to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on my Flask server with port 50000?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

On the the server the request is being made to, you must set it so that it sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in the response. If that’s the server on port 40000, then that’s where you set it.

If the server running on port 50000 is just one serving the web application with the JavaScript client code that you making the request from, then you don’t need to set that server to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the server the request is being made to. i.e. the server running on port 40000.

The server which already has the data must grant permission to the page on the other server to read that data.